# It is possible to match only double character?

Tags: javascript, regex

It is possible to match only double character?

example:

M - false

MM - **true**

MMM - false

MMMM - false

How can I make Regular Expression to solve problem?

Comment: with Regexp you can

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I use Regexp. but I cannot make regular expression to solve this problem. I want to match only double character 'MM' but my expression match both MM and MMMM.

Comment: Which is your input and expected output? Does `M{2}` fit somewhere?

Comment: This is fundamentally difficult in JavaScript due to there being no *lookbehind* **if** you are after **any** repeated character. If you are only after the literal "M" character, then it's not so hard

Comment: @I.G.Pascual input is date format. "YY/MM/DD/" or "YYYY/MMMM/DDDD". I want to replace "M" with only "MM".

Comment: I'm getting that [*"X-Y Problem"*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) feeling

Comment: @HyunjinLee What's your problem in using `"YY/MM/DD".replace(/M{2}/,"M")`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean RegEx by 'Regular Expression', the answer shoud be simple as follows.

```
M{2}
```

More specifically, you can use this ensure **only** 2 'M's are matched by requiring it to begin and end with other characters. However the following example may not find a 'MM' if it's at either the beginning or the end of a line.

```
[^M]+M{2}[^M]+
```

To match a line that contain **exactly** and **only** what you want, add a caret[^] and a dollar[$] to specify the beginning and the end of a line, respectively.

```
^M{2}$
```

Note that Basic Regular Expression (BRE) may not work as intended sometimes. You'll probably need Extended Regular Expression (ERE) instead, usually specified with a command-line option to a program.

Comment: I'd end that second expression with `[^M]*` in case the double char is at the end of the string